# Javascript insert image as a div background

Tags: javascript, background-image, tumblr

I'm trying to insert my lastest tumblr post image directly as the background-image of a div on my website.

I'm able to add an image src with this code

```
<img border='0' style='margin:0' width='100%' id='TumblrMagic' src='' alt='' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://myblog.tumblr.com/api/read/json?number=1&type=photo'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            document.getElementById('TumblrMagic').setAttribute('src', tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500']);
    /script>
```

But for style reason, I'd like to be able to put it as a background-image of a div.
I'm digging around this

```
<div id="TumblrMagic"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('TumblrMagic').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
</script>
```

Now I'm trying to replace `imageUrl` with the code that loads the image  `tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500']` but I'm not fluent in javascript.
Anyone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append img element to div:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var div = document.getElementById('TumblrMagic');
    var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500'];
    div.appendChild(image);
</script>
```

or set background image to div:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var  image = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500'];
    var div = document.getElementById('TumblrMagic');
        div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';
        div.style.width = '100%'; //change it or apply by CSS
        div.style.height = '768px'; //change it or apply by CSS
    </script>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it ads the picture directly and not as a background-image of my div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var imageUrl = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500'];
```

Comment: I was just trying this a moment ago but I only got a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`...

Comment: Can you put this before : console.log(tumblr_api_read); and tell me what you'll fine in the console ?

Comment: I can read this `Object {tumblelog: Object, posts-start: 0, posts-total: 82, posts-type: "photo", posts: Array[20]}`

Comment: So I don't see a problem. Can you try this to be sure ? console.log(tumblr_api_read.posts[0]); and see if "photo-url-500" is in there ?

Comment: console.log(imageUrl) ? And I think document.getElementById('TumblrMagic').src = imageUrl; would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry Thibault, the answer has been found just above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thibault very very useful comments.